# Unable to dump results of a DB query in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea, datagrip

I connected to remote PostgreSQL database using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1 successfully and executed some select queries on one of the tables. I got the results. I wanted to dump the results data to a file or the clipboard, but the 'Dump Data' command is disabled. Any idea why that might be or how to tell the reason? Thanks.

[image]

It does not matter which output format I choose from the Select on the left of the Dump Data button. I have updated the DB driver to the latest version.

I am using:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1
Build #IU-172.3544.35, built on July 31, 2017
Mac OS X 10.12.6
```

Comment: I know this sound like voodoo, but did you try restarting IJ? Sometimes after repeatedly executing a maven goal by double-clicking it in the maven window, it gets disabled, grayed out. I haven't figured out why, but it comes back to normal after restarting IJ. Btw if you go to the database view, expand your connection nodes and select one table, when you right click it you should see a `Dump data to File` item. Can you select any of the options or are they all disabled?

Comment: Oh, invalidate caches and restart did help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeating query as suggested did not help. Nor did a regular restart. Invalidate Caches and Restart did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The [**Dump Data**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/working-with-query-results.html#copying_saving_table_data) **To File/Clipboard** action becomes disabled for those query results (and corresponding [SQL Console](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/working-with-database-consoles.html)) for which **database parameters** (like current database/schema or search path for Postgres/Redshift) **have been changed** **after** you got those query results.

I.e. when you execute select query using one current schema (search path in Postgres/Redshift) and then change the schema (i.e. with the 'use' statement) to another schema(search path in Postgres/Redshift).

And it should get enabled after you re-run the query with the changed parameters or revert them back.

Comment: Re-running query did not help, but invalidating caches did.